# How to select specific lines and specific columns

Tags: r, statistics, database

I have  a data frame that contain lot of columns and lines, like this for example

```
Column1   Column2 
5            T1
1            T2
1            T3
1            T1
2            T1
1            T1
2            T1
1            T1
```

I want to extract just lines that have the value 1 in column 1 and Value T1 in Column 2

So the result I want is

```
Column1   Column2 
1            T1
1            T1
1            T1
```

Can you tell me please how I can do that

Comment: Hi @James what code have you written so far? You must have imported into R and done some basic dataframe work.

Comment: Hello , thank you very much for you answer , yes i tried this one : Pokemon_2 <- dropRows(ds, Pokemon$Generation == 1 , Pokemon$Type_1=="Water" )   but it didn't work  , Error in dropRows(ds, Pokemon$Generation == 1, Pokemon$Type_1 == "Water") : 
  could not find function "dropRows"

Comment: You should look at the `subset` function. Please google "filter data frame by column value" - much like writing `for` loops in basic programming languages, it is a basic operation that does not warrant creating new posts on forums.

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because it is a basic R operation has nothing to do with bioinformatics specifically

Answer (score 2):

You can simply use subset function in R and use the code given below,

```
    new_dataframe <- 
    subset(name_of_your_dataframe,Column1 == 1 && 
    Column2 ==  "T1")
```

Please keep in mind that R is case sensitive and you should be careful while using the variable names.